# Invalid path when using ng g class in Angular 2

Tags: wordpress, angular

I am busy trying to create an Angular 2 theme over WordPress. I am in the initial stages of creating the app now but when I run `ng g class /posts/post` in Git Bash, I get an error "Invalid path: `C:\Users\Mike\dev\Saxum\wpng2\src\app\C:` is not a valid path."

[image]

Any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the leading slash:

```
ng g class posts/post
```